# WooCommerce - currency selector

Tags: wordpress, localization, woocommerce, currency

In WooCommerce, is it possible to display a specific currency based on user settings (user required to sign in)?

I need it for a platform where I don't want to make all currency versions available to the users, but only make them able to see one that I choose e.g. in the user settings.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this "[WooCommerce Custom Currencies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-currencies/)" plugin is help full for you.